# Javascript function won't work in a loop but does if run individually

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I would like to preselect a choice in several (x30) option box forms depending on an associated variable state .

Each option box has an id : selectbox_1 to selectbox_30

To pre-select the proper choice in each option box, i use the following that works great :

```js
setSelectedIndex(document.getElementById('selectbox_1'), getXMLValue(xmlData, 'SCHEDULE_1'));

setSelectedIndex(document.getElementById('selectbox_'), getXMLValue(xmlData, 'SCHEDULE_2'));

...

setSelectedIndex(document.getElementById('selectbox_30'), getXMLValue(xmlData, 'SCHEDULE_30'));
```

Because it should be easier and clearer to do that in a loop, i tried the following, but for some unknown reasons, it won't work, would you please help ?

```js
<script type = "text/javascript">
  for (i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
    setSelectedIndex(document.getElementById('selectbox_' + i), getXMLValue(xmlData, 'SCHEDULE_' + i));
  } 
</script>
```

```js
function setSelectedIndex(s, valsearch) {
  // Loop through all the items in drop down list
  for (i = 0; i < s.options.length; i++) {
    if (s.options[i].value == valsearch) {
      // Item is found. Set its property and exit
      s.options[i].selected = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return;
}
```

```html
<form method="get" action="sensors.htm" id="sensor_1">
  <select name="schedule" id="selectbox_1" value="~maj_sensor_schedule(1)~">
  <option value="0">never</option>
  <option value="1">every 1 minute</option>
 <option value="2">every 5 minutes</option>
 <option value="3">every 10 minutes</option>
 <option value="4">every 15 minutes</option>
 <option value="5">every 30 minutes</option>
 <option value="6">every hour</option>
 <option value="7">every 2 hours</option>
 <option value="8">every 4 hours</option>
 <option value="9">every 8 hours</option>
 <option value="10">every 12 hours</option>
 <option value="11">everyday</option>
 <option value="12">every week</option>
</select>
  <input src="./checked.png" onclick="document.getElementById('sensor_1').submit()" align="center" type="image"></form>



<form method="get" action="sensors.htm">

  <select name="schedule" id="selectbox_2" value="~maj_sensor_schedule(2)~">
   
  <option value="0">never</option>
  <option value="1">every 1 minute</option>
  <option value="2">every 5 minutes</option>
  <option value="3">every 10 minutes</option>
  <option value="4">every 15 minutes</option>
  <option value="5">every 30 minutes</option>
  <option value="6">every hour</option>
  <option value="7">every 2 hours</option>
  <option value="8">every 4 hours</option>
  <option value="9">every 8 hours</option>
  <option value="10">every 12 hours</option>
  <option value="11">everyday</option>
  <option value="12">every week</option>
  </select>
  <input src="./checked.png" onclick="document.getElementById('sensor_2').submit()" align="center" type="image"> </form>
```

Comment: What does "it won't work" mean **specifically**? Did you check the console for errors?

Comment: With Chrome console (F12) there is no error, but the option boxes are not updated as expected.

Comment: You're not declaring ˋi` as a local variable in either case. Add a ˋvar i;` at the beginning of each of the functions where you use it. And add `'use strict';` at the beginning of each script to avoid any further such issues.

Comment: Tried the following, but still no change :  `<script type="text/javascript">
"use strict";

for(i = 1; i <= 10 ; i++)
setSelectedIndex(document.getElementById("selectbox_"+i),"~maj_sensor_schedule("+i+")~");


function setSelectedIndex(s, valsearch)
{
var i;
 
for (i = 0; i< s.options.length; i++)
{ 
 if (s.options[i].value == valsearch)
 {
 // Item is found. Set its property and exit
 s.options[i].selected = true;
 break;
 }
}
return;
}`